# jQuery Ajaxy plugin : after call ajax on main menu, use the plugin again on a new menu

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using Ajaxy on main menu of a website.
My problem is that when I get the results from the ajax call I create dynamically a tree menu, so I have to use the same function on the tree menu as on the main menu.
The tree menu is created with this code:

```
$("#tree .menu").html($("#main .menu").html());
```

Is it possible to make it work even with another plugin?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You want to duplicate an exisiting element in the DOM and add events (click, drag, plugin, etc..) to it if I understand your question correctly.

If so, then you can do it like this:

- Clone the element you want to duplicate with `.clone()` and store it in an variable (will be an jQuery object).
- Work with the object like you want it (add events, change html etc.)
- Put it in the DOM where you want it when done

Here is an simple example:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.tree li').click(click_func);

        $('a').click(function() {
            var $tree_copy = $('.tree:first').clone();

            // use the cloned object as an jQuery object
            $tree_copy.find('li').click(click_func2);

            // add it to the DOM
            $('body').append($tree_copy);
        });
    });
```

[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/kNebA/)

Comment: Thank you for your response but this is not my problem.. I have found the solution without using any history plugin, but now I have to make it work with back button and bookmarks. For this reason I use jquery-ajaxy plugin.

Comment: Do you mean that I have to copy the menu before ajaxy plugin is starting?
I tried this but I didnt get it work.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you descibe what you want in steps? 1) user clicks...

Comment: 1) user clicks on the menu,
2) Then get an html file with ajax,
3) on the same time created a tree menu next to the text of html,
4) now user could click either on the main menu or on the tree menu with the same result.

I found a solution. I create the tree menu on a hidden div, and then when user clicks a menu the tree menu is appearing.

I have done all of these with jquery ajax and the website is working well..but I cant handle the history. The best way would be to use history.js cause I have already the working functions, but I am new to jquery and javascript, so its difficult for me.